# Alternately sending and receiving byte[] using Socket

Tags: java

I need to send and receive alternately byte [] using Socket. How to do this ?
What wrappers to use ?
Is this ok or I can do this on quicker way

```
public boolean SendMessage(byte[] data){
        try{
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
            OutputStream socketOutputStream = (OutputStream) socket.getOutputStream();
            socketOutputStream.write(data);
            socket.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            System.err.println(exc.getStackTrace());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

After call of this function I call function for receiving bytes, and again send =>receive and so on. Is there quicker way to do this ?

Comment: As a side note: method names shouldn't start with an uppercase character. It might look like a class name, but it isn't. Check ["Naming Conventions" in "Code Conventions for the Java(TM) Programming Language"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same socket for reading and writing, just synchronize the two apps so that one read while the other writes, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new socket each time for sending/receiving and then closing it, you should use the same socket.

Say, create two threads. One as the SenderThread and the other as ReceiverThread.
The SenderThread creates a socket and then gets the outputstream and you can have a while loop with a flag to indicate whether it should run or not.

```
Eg: while (running){
```

The same thing should be done in the ReceiverThread. Create socket and inputstream. Then run the while loop.

In the while loop, you can provide your logic of writing/reading the data to/from the stream.

Use wait and notify so that the threads run in harmony..